# How to pass a wrapped C++ object to a Javascript callback?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm trying to write a Node.js module, using C++, that wraps and exposes some classes from [libhdf5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/doc/cpplus_RM/index.html).

I'm currently interested in two classes from libhdf5. The first one is `File`, and it opens an hdf5 file. The second one is `Group`, and it represents groups within that file. You get Group objects from a File object.

I've written some code in which I create a `File` object and attempt to get a `Group` from it. I am trying to make my Node.js module as JavaScripty as possible, so I want to return the group using a callback. So, I am trying to code my module so that it's used like this:

```
var hdf5 = require('hdf5');
var file = new hdf5.File('/tmp/example.h5');
file.getGroup('foobar', function (err, group) { console.log(group); });
```

So, in the C++ code for my `File` wrapper, I'd have a function that maps to the `getGroup` function here, and it'd call the given anonymous function, passing in any errors as well as the new `Group` object wrapper.

Given that this sounded to me like what the Node.js documentation shows to be a [factory of wrapped objects](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_factory_of_wrapped_objects), I have modeled my `Group` code after the examples there.

So, I have my `Group` wrapper coded up, but am stuck trying to instantiate it. I don't know enough yet to know how to stray away from using the v8 `Arguments` class for function parameters. Because of that, I can't seem to be able to pass in some parameters that I need for my v8 persistent constructor function (because I am instantiating this from C++, and not from JS-land).

Comment: Hi Ryan. The links to your repo are all dead, presumably it has been deleted (this is why external links are discouraged). Would you repair this question in order to restore it how it was when it was asked? Ideally the code would be brought into the question itself, to avoid this happening again. It might be OK to delete the last three paragraphs and still maintain some meaning, what do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are almost there. You don't need to pass `Arguments` to `Group::Instantiate`. Just pass what you need and use the constructor to create the new instance of `Group`. For example:

```
Handle<Value> Group::Instantiate(const std::string& name) {
    HandleScope scope;

    Local<v8::Value> argv[1] = {
        Local<v8::Value>::New(String::New(name.c_str()))
    };

    return scope.Close(Constructor->NewInstance(1, argv));
}
```

The method `Group::New` does the rest of the construction work.

```
Handle<Value> Group::New(const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    if (!args[0]->IsString()) {
        return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(String::New("First argument must be a string")));
    }
    const std::string name(*(String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString())));
    Group * const group = new Group(name);
    bar->Wrap(args.This());

    return args.This();
}
```

In `File::OpenGroup` you can do this:

```
Handle<Value> File::OpenGroup (const Arguments& args) {
    HandleScope scope;

    if (args.Length() != 2 || !args[0]->IsString() || !args[1]->IsFunction()) {
        ThrowException(Exception::SyntaxError(String::New("expected name, callback")));
        return scope.Close(Undefined());
    }
    const std::string name(*(String::Utf8Value(args[0]->ToString())));
    Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[1]);

    const unsigned argc = 2;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
        Local<Value>::New(Null()),
        Local<Value>::New(Group::Instantiate(name))
    };
    callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);

    return scope.Close(Undefined());
}
```

Comment: Is that to say that you need a factory method (`Group::Instantiate`) to return an instance of another class?